# Prop-Type checking in constructor

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm writing a library and want to do prop types validation in my component constructors.

I'm not really satisfied with the current options for prop types checking.  The prop-types package only warns, so when testing I have to spy on the console.  It also only checks for the primitive types, which is limiting. 
There are other packages that in combination would do what I'm looking for, but I don't want to add too many packages to my library.

Any issue with this approach?

Comment: Users don't care if a proptype has a warning, I would suggest keeping it under the hood as it's only helpful to developers (who should be checking their props and validation)

Comment: Just off the top of my head, I don't think doing it in the constructor is a great idea since that only gets called on initial mount.  If the props passed down from the parent change, that won't get called again.

That said, the `prop-types` package allows you to write custom validators.  You'll still have to keep an eye on the console, but maybe that helps?

Comment: Custom validators is definitely a thing, you can use regex, type checking, etc.

Comment: Thanks everybody, custom validators was something I missed.  I guess I can live with spying on the console.  Thanks for the point about only initial mount, too.

Comment: Use TS instead or in addition to prop-types. That's what we usually use when we want to be notified about type problems in good time.